# before printing excel worksheet, disable if it was done by file menu and enable if by button on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, onbeforeprint

I'm trying to resolve an issue with printing a sheet in Excel. So I was wondering whether there is a way to allow printing via button only. In ThisWorkbook I put the code below. What should I put in a module? How to pass 'button_used' variable from module back to ThisWorkbook?

```vb
Public Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    'disables print if button is not used
    If button_used = False Then
        MsgBox "Print is disabled, use button"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use a Global `AllowPrint` flag which you set to True set in the code attached to the "print" button - if that's not set in the `Workbook_BeforePrint` method then set `Cancel = True`.  Don't forget to set back to False once printing is done.

Comment: And how the code should be? I declared a global variable in private module via Public keyword, but I can not access it in ThisWorkbook module

Comment: Should be fine if you declare it in a regular (non-private) module.

Comment: Many thanks Tim, everything turned up great :)